# How to get to redirected by using PHP cURL from document.location.href?

Tags: web-scraping, curl, redirect, php-curl

I am trying to scrape a website that opens normally using the browser. However whenever I open the link using cURL , I get to an intermediary redirecting page that shows "Redirecting... Please, wait."

My code is as below:

```
$url = "https://codeforces.com/problemset";

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$result = curl_exec($ch); //returning the source code for the url.
echo $result;
```

Instead of returing the contents of the url `curl_exec($ch)` returns the below values:

```
<html>

<body>Redirecting... Please, wait.<script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function toNumbers(d) {
            var e = [];
            d.replace(/(..)/g, function(d) {
                e.push(parseInt(d, 16))
            });
            return e
        }

        function toHex() {
            for (var d = [], d = 1 == arguments.length && arguments[0].constructor == Array ? arguments[0] : arguments, e = "", f = 0; f < d.length; f++) e += (16 > d[f] ? "0" : "") + d[f].toString(16);
            return e.toLowerCase()
        }
        var a = toNumbers("e9ee4b03c1d0822987185d27bca23378"),
            b = toNumbers("188fafdbe0f87ef0fc2810d5b3e34705"),
            c = toNumbers("d797a6b5b9d48f1ca8bcbddbe6654d10");
        document.cookie = "RCPC=" + toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c, 2, a, b)) + "; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/";
        document.location.href = "https://codeforces.com/problemset?tags=1000-1500&f0a28=1";
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

this results in a page that shows simply this [output in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DL8xN.png)

The same code have worked before a few days. The link is still manually accessible .
How can I fix this?

Is there someway to get redirected to `document.location.href` using cURL ?

Answer (score 0):

cURL can't execute any JavaScript code. JavaScript code is executed within the browser.
Also, the implementation of this kind of technique is used to stop unwanted web scraping. Since the site you are trying to scrape has set it up, scraping it maybe illegal or harmful for the website.

If you still need to scrape such websites you can try selenium or some other headless browser. Or a different dedicated web scrapping tool.